# Using fullCalendar and getting the wrong day after formatting

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using full calendar and what should be very basic "dayClick"  I am having trouble getting the date I clicked as a string.

```
dayClick: function(d){
    var thisDay = d._d;
    console.log(thisDay);
    console.log(moment(thisDay).format('yyyy-mm-dd'));
    console.log(thisDay.toString());
},
```

produces three very strange results. The 1st one I get. it is the date from the day object that I clicked on, which is correct, the second one is the result of trying to let momentJs format the date. the third is just using js toString function help out but it seems to change the date from the 4th to the 3rd.

What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Also, your formating tokens don't match Moment's. They should be `YYYY-MM-DD`.  See the docs.

Answer (score 0):

`thisDay.toString()` is converting it to your local time instead of showing the UTC date.

You can use `thisDay.toISOString()` instead.